Airflow log not shown in Web UI between retries
I'm running Airflow 2.9.1 Docker on localhost with LocalExecutor. Whenever there is an error and the task goes into retries (task becomes yellow, up_for_retry status), the log does not show up on Web UI, only a serial number, as shown in the attached screenshot. I can find the log files in the Docker container /opt/airflow/logs/task_id=xxx/attempt=n.log, which looks normally. If manually setting the task to Fail or Success, the log shows up again. How can I fix this?

